# Import folder of raster files as a numpy array

Tags: python, gdal, numpy

I'm attempting to run a CNN model with raster files for environmental observations and I'm trying to import a folder of tiff files as the input for the model. I'm relatively new to python and ML and need help with reading the folder of rasters as a 3d numpy array. Below code has been my attempt at reading the folder with gdal:

```
flix = r'/Desktop/x'
fliy = r'/Desktop/y'

# in_directory = r'C:\Data'
files_to_process = glob(os.path.join(flix, '*.tif')

for data_path in files_to_process:
    raster_dataset = gdal.Open(data_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
```

Note: I somehow am receiving a syntax error at the for loop definition itself as well.

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket `)` on the `files_to_process = glob(os.path.join(flix, '*.tif')` line, hence the `SyntaxError`.  To read into a numpy array, use `raster_dataset.ReadAsArray()` https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html

Comment: What does the input images look like, RGB, Greyscale, multispectral, hyper-spectral?

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment of @user2856.

```
flix = r'/Desktop/x'
fliy = r'/Desktop/y'

# in_directory = r'C:\Data'
files_to_process = glob(os.path.join(flix, '*.tif')) # closing bracket for glob()

for data_path in files_to_process:
    raster_dataset = gdal.Open(data_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
    array = raster_dataset.ReadAsArray() # This will read the file as a numpy array. It will also overwrite the array with each iteration of the loop.
```

You will also need to read the label (`fliy`) and match it to the corresponding image (`flix`).